# Class to color text and key words like notepad ++ when editing XML or code

Tags: c#

I would like to implement a class to provide me with a nice text display that highlights key words. I am displaying SQL and XML codes and the notepad ++ works well.

Does anyone know of a class i could implement with similar features?

Even the way stack overflow does it when you set something as code. Like the example blow is text that i would display, and stack overflow formats and makes it look pretty for me.

This is what i'm looking for.

```
<!-- Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Trial -->
<File friendlyName="Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Trial" url="http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/0/6/4067968E-5530-4A08-B8EC-17D2B3F02C35/vs_ultimateweb.exe" installArgs="/q /full /norestart" estDownloadTime="00:00:20" estInstallTime="01:10:00" />
<!-- Silverlight 4 Tools for Visual Studio -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested in [ColorCode - Syntax Highlighting/Colorization for .NET](http://colorcode.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Problem with ColorCode, I downloaded the code and is it uses 3rd party DLL's itself.  Kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: @Chizl, 3rd party dlls are related to unit testing and building, why do you think that is a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/), the core component that Notepad++ uses to render text.

There exists [some .Net wrappers](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/) you can use.